# How to display list of list of string array on jsp?

Tags: jsp

In spring mvc i am sending List of objects in a model to jsp.
**List**

my bean DtoDocument is as below

```
public class DtoDocument{

private String label;
private String[] title;
private List<String[]> content;

and there getter and setter.......

}
```

each entry  in List represents a table whose label is given for each object, title[] contains title of columns and each eantry in list represents a row of table with string array contains cell values.

My question is how to iterate over the parent list i.e List and inside that  print the label and iterate over title array and then iterate over and list and inside that iterate over the inside array.

According to my understanding

What i have done is below:-

```
<c:forEach items="${parentList}" var="tables">
<table>
    <c:out value="${tables.label}" />
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <c:forEach items="${tables.title}" var="titles">
      <th><c:out value="${titles}" /></th>
    </c:forEach>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <c:forEach items="${tables.content}" var="contents">
      <tr>
      <c:forEach items="${contents}" var="cell">
      <td><c:out value="${cell}" /></td>
      </c:forEach>
    </c:forEach>
      </tr>
     </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</table>
</c:forEach>
```

So what i have done is correct because i am new to this ?

Comment: What is your question ? . Is it working fine on rendering or any problem you are facing ?

Comment: Actually I dont have database ready right now so i cannot check what i have written is correct or not, so i jus want to confirm that my code is right or is thre any problem with the code?

Comment: then instead pass some static models as you thought that will come from db to the jsp